# docker ubuntu wont start again on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, docker, 23.04

In an online docker training course, the instructor mentioned that he has an
Ubuntu virtual machine installed with Docker
So I created via virtual box on my windows 11 host a ubuntu 23.04 VM which for it I allocated 60GB of storage, and pressed the pre-allocate (which I thought will allocate the full 60GB not dynamically)
when I run df -h
I see only 7about 7gb on my vm...

[df -h output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULg5V.png)
After installing docker engine via the documentation and when trying to run docker compose on an app from the course i get a no space left on device error...

[docker compose up output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Cc8.png)

can someone explain why this is happening although I allocated 60GB of storage?

help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Are you sure the VirtualBox instance has Ubuntu *installed*? Looks like you’re using the Live Session. If you see an icon on your desktop that says “Install Ubuntu”, you may want to click on that and follow the wizard 

Comment: Your right I hadn't installed Ubuntu, For some reason when clicking the button it doesn't do a thing..                                                                                                                             Next time I will select ubuntu(safe mode) when booting up instead of try ubuntu                                   to see if that will work on a new vm.                                                                               But by the way, any idea why it wouldn't work for me from the Live Session? Thanks!!

Comment: It have the same problem when trying what I specified, Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: FYI:   If doing an IT course you should know details matter. Ubuntu has products that use the *year* format (eg. 22) which are *flavors* of the the more widely used *year.month* products (eg. 22 is a *snap* only flavor of 22.04 Server). Precision matters.

Comment: Hi, the course is for docker and There wasn't much focus on virtual box...                        I don't seem to understand If and how it is connected to what I specified... if it is, would you mind clarifying? I'm afraid I'm new to ubuntu